# Using numba on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cuda, numba

I am using AWS AMI `Deep Learning AMI GPU TensorFlow 2.10.0 (Amazon Linux 2) 20220927` to run some code that uses `numba` in `python 3.9`. However, I get this error:

```
numba.cuda.cudadrv.error.CudaSupportError: Error at driver init: Call to cuInit results in CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE (100)
```

Which suggests to me there is no CUDA GPU installed, which is not what AWS says. What do I need to do to make this work here? This code works elsewhere, so it is an environment specific problem.

Comment: What instance do you use?

Comment: The base AMI is `Deep Learning AMI GPU TensorFlow 2.10.0 (Amazon Linux 2) 20220927` with `t3.large`. According to AWS CUDA is installed on this base image

Answer (score 2):

`t3.large` instances **do not have GPU**. The `Deep Learning AMI GPU TensorFlow 2.10.0 (Amazon Linux 2)` is only operating system. For GPU to work, you actually need to have some GPUs with your instance.

Please check [AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) for instances with GPU, such as P3 for example.

Comment: That would make sense. Though what does this mean in this case? when I type `nvcc --version` I get this response:
`nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Feb_14_21:12:58_PST_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.152
Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29618528_0`

Comment: @sobmortin354 — it means absolutely nothing. You can install the CUDA compiler on any machine whether it has a CUDA capable GPU or not

Comment: OK, I have changed to using p2 instances and am still getting the same error. What else do I need to do to get a GPU EC2 instance working? I have set up EC2 instances without GPU before and never had any problems, so I don't understand why this is so different. Thanks